# Как в BlackBoxComponentBuilder открыть документ для редактирования программно

Tags: ide

Пытаюсь открыть файл программно. Есть HostCmds.Open, которая вызывает диалог открытия файла. Есть StdApi.OpenDoc, которая принимает возвращаемый параметр, т.е. я не пойму, как запихать её в Commander. Какую команду нужно подать, чтобы программно открыть в IDE файл с заданным именем (и путём)?

Answer (score 0):

Меню/Файл/Новый.

В нём написать:

```
MODULE Пляж; IMPORT Views, StdApi;
PROCEDURE Од*(Путь: ARRAY OF CHAR);
  VAR v:Views.View; BEGIN StdApi.OpenDoc(Путь, v); END Од;
END Пляж.

(* 
♥"Пляж.Од('c:\ob\71\x.odc')"
*)
```

Вместо сердечка вставить "Commander" (Ctrl-Q)

Сохранить в файл Пляж.odc

Меню/Разработка/Компилировать и выгрузить

Далее нажимаем на Commander